# Generalize code !?!

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a lot of constraints - tests  that looks like this:

**Test for Lastname not null**

```
BEGIN TRY    
  set @TEST_TEXT = 'insert into Person.Person lastname = NULL- Expect ERROR_NULL_CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION';
  select @PostalCode = max(dbo.PostalCodeCity.PostalCode) +1 from dbo.PostalCodeCity; -- Generate new valid postal code
  insert into Person.Person (Firstname, Lastname, AddressLine1, PostalCode) values ('Jens', null, 'Møgelbjergvej 34', @PostalCode)
  insert into @TestResults values(1, @TEST_TEXT)
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
  insert into @TestResults values(case when ERROR_NUMBER() = @ERROR_NULL_CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION then 0 else 1 end, @TEST_TEXT)
  if ERROR_NUMBER() != @ERROR_NULL_CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION 
    exec usp_GetErrorInfo
END CATCH;
```

**Test for AddressLine1 not null**

```
BEGIN TRY    
  set @TEST_TEXT = 'insert into Person.Person AddressLine1 = NULL- Expect ERROR_NULL_CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION';
  select @PostalCode = max(dbo.PostalCodeCity.PostalCode) +1 from dbo.PostalCodeCity; -- Generate new valid postal code
  insert into Person.Person (Firstname, Lastname, AddressLine1, PostalCode) values ('Jens', 'Borrisholt', null, @PostalCode)
  insert into @TestResults values(1, @TEST_TEXT)
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
  insert into @TestResults values(case when ERROR_NUMBER() = @ERROR_NULL_CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION then 0 else 1 end, @TEST_TEXT)
  if ERROR_NUMBER() != @ERROR_NULL_CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION 
    exec usp_GetErrorInfo
END CATCH;
```

And a lot like this. My question is could I somehow generalize theese tests so I won't have to write allmost the same 200 times? Put it into a procedure or something else?

Comment: What is the point of these tests? Isn't it easier to verify the constraint exists?

Comment: The point of theese tests are to the my constraints by using them.

Comment: What is "at"TestResults - is it a temp table - where is the variable "at"TestResults declared.

Comment: Test result is declares in the top of the script 

declare @TestResults table 
(
  TestResult int,
  TestDescription varchar(200) 
);

Comment: You should just verify that the column doesn't allow null which can be validated from checking the system views. There is no point testing whether SQL Server will disallow inserting nulls into a column that does not allow null unless you are in fact on the SQL Server developer team.

Comment: Thankyou for your advice @MartinSmith, but can the above code be generalized?

Comment: Well as I don't think you should be doing it that way then I'm not going to spend any time considering that. The approach of `SELECT is_nullable
FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = object_id('Person.Person') AND name = 'Lastname'` is obviously open to parameterisation and can be made generic trivially though.

Comment: I would generate the Entire SQL bloc on the fly form (c# ?) code for one time execution.  Not Dynamic SQL but SQL that gets the full parser treatment.   If the parser is Not important to you then you could use DynamicSQL.  Your above tests look like 4 records in a table of dynamic sql with simple string replace.  I am assuming you are looking at this as a repeatable test suite - this is one of many tests.  If the tests are just DDL tests I would consider abandoning the test suite for another solution or push it up to the application layer like calling the real AddZip API for your app.